# error while inserting data in an array- invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, c, matrix

I am getting this error when trying to compile my program the code part I am getting this error is:

```
matrixType MatrixADT::add(matrixType M1, matrixType M2){
    matrixType M;
    for(int i=0;i<M1.matDimension;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<M2.matDimension;j++){
            M.matDimension[i][j] = M1.matDimension[i][j] + M2.matDimension[i][j];//Here is the error
        }
    }
    return M;
}
```

Complete code can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/L2hGih8h).

I have googled for this and found several questions with the same but cant figure out whats the problem.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c]? Why are you passing your arguments *by value*? And... ***what is the error***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the definition of `matrixType`:

```
struct matrixType{
    int matDimension;
    int matValues[10][10];
};
```

You need to change

```
M.matDimension[i][j] = M1.matDimension[i][j] + M2.matDimension[i][j];
```

to

```
M.matValues[i][j] = M1.matValues[i][j] + M2.matValues[i][j];
```

Comment: Oops!! How fool was I any ways Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it as solution. Thanks!